# Global HTML Safari Extension

Tags: javascript, html, safari-extension

I am creating a Safari Extension which removes certain elements from some websites. However, because I have a lot of elements to remove it is getting a bit slow. I have seen that you can add a 'Global Page File' which handles all the logic and can increase the speed. Is it possible to put all the logic for the element removing in a HTML and then create a script which says that variable is true? I know there is something about an event listener but I'm not sure how to use it.

Example HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var data = document.createElement('style');
    data.appendChild(document.createTextNode( '#id {display: none !important}' ));
    document.documentElement.insertBefore(data);
    };
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Example js file

```
data = true
```

Comment: You must be repeating something for each element you want to hide. Where is the repetition happening? Are you creating a new `style` element for each element to hide? (This would be horrible.) Are you creating a new style rule for each element and then appending that text node to a single stylesheet? If that's it, a better approach would be to create the entire stylesheet as one string, and then put it in the `style` element in one shot.

Moving the logic to a global page script would not help, I think.

Comment: Is it possible to put jQuery into the script section of the HTML then the js file to receive those settings from it?

Comment: You can load jQuery as another injected script, and then your own injected script will have access to it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Could you send an example?

Comment: I could send you a sample Info.plist, but not sure if that would be helpful. All you have to do is place a jQuery JS file in your extension folder and then, in Extension Builder, add a new injected script, specifying the jQuery file. If you add it as a "start" script and have your own injected script as an "end" script, then you can be sure jQuery will already be loaded by the time your script loads.

Comment: I have already done that. I'm just wondering is there a way to improve performance in removing the elements.